# netplan network configuration with vlans and bridges

Tags: networking, netplan

I'm trying to move a network configuration with vlans and bridges from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 (netplan). I've read a few similar questions and answers on here but still cannot get it to work. This is the current configuration in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

auto eno1.104
iface eno1.104 inet manual
        pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eno1 up
        vlan-raw-device eno1

auto br104
iface br104 inet static
        bridge_ports eno1.104
        metric 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
        address 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.254
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: See https://netplan.io/examples for some guidance.

Comment: If I could downvote that comment, I would.